# warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c++builder

Here my code

```
   if(bSelected)
{
    clrTextSave=pDC->SetTextColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT));
    clrBkSave=pDC->SetBkColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
    pDC->FillRect(rcAllLabels,&CBrush(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT)));
}
else
    pDC->FillRect(rcAllLabels,&CBrush(m_clrTextBk));
```

When I complie on Visual studio 2008 it give me :
warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue 
I don't know how to fix this warning? Plz somebody help? Thank you !

Comment: Warning point to  pDC->FillRect(rcAllLabels,&CBrush(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT)));

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are getting the warning (which should be an error because you should always compile your code using the highest warning level) because you are creating a temporary and using it's address.  To prevent this warning, you need to create a local variable instead:

```
if(bSelected)
{
    clrTextSave = pDC->SetTextColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT));
    clrBkSave = pDC->SetBkColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
    CBrush brush(::GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT)); // create a local variable
    pDC->FillRect(rcAllLabels, &brush); // use its address
}
else
{
    CBrush brush(m_clrTextBk); // same thing here
    pDC->FillRect(rcAllLabels, &brush);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zac Howland so much.now it seem running well

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  You are dead wrong here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zyb9yb4.aspx

Comment: @ZacHowland: there is a **huge** difference between a **local** variable and a **temporary**. Unless I am misunderstanding your answer and the code is a *solution* to the problem, if that is the case, then sorry for the comment.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  Did you even **read** what I wrote?  I showed him code to fix his problem ...

Comment: @ZacHowland: Yes, and to be honest I did not find it clear. *you are creating a temporary and using it's address: [code goes here]* The colon is usually employed to provide an example of what was explained before. In your case the construct is contradictory: *you are doing A: B*. That confused me. Again, sorry for the comment (which I have removed)

Comment: The OP seemed to have no such problem discerning it, but I'll add a clarification anyway.